# How can I fix my for loop in void result() function?

Tags: c++, oop

The for loop in the result() function doesn't give the correct output, in fact it doubles the required output. I have tried doing total_marks = marks[1] + marks[2]...+ marks[5] and it works fine that way but I want to know what's wrong with the for loop.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student{
protected:
char name[20];
int roll;
int age;
public:
void input(){
    cout<<"Enter name: ";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter roll number: ";
    cin>>roll;
    cout<<"Enter age: ";
    cin>>age;
}
};

class Test: public Student{
protected:
int marks[5];
public:
void getMarks(){
    cout<<"Enter marks: "<<endl;
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        cout<<"Subject "<<i<<":";
        cin>>marks[i];
    }
}
void displayMarks(){
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Student Name: "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Student Roll no: "<<roll<<endl;
    cout<<"Student age: "<<age<<endl;
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        cout<<"Marks in Suject "<<i<<": "<<marks[i]<<endl;
    } 
   }
 };

class Result: public Test{
protected:
int total_marks=0;
float percentage;
public:
void result(){
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        total_marks = total_marks + marks[i];
    }
    cout<<"Total marks: "<<total_marks<<endl;
    percentage = (float)total_marks/5;
    cout<<"Percentage: "<<percentage<<endl;
}
};

int main(){
Result r;
r.input();
r.getMarks();
r.displayMarks();
r.result();
}
```

Comment: The array `int marks[5]` has 5 elements numbered `0` through `4`. Your program accesses `marks[5]` and thereby exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. What appears to happen in practice is that `total_marks` just happens to be located in memory right after `marks` array, and so whenever you assign to `marks[5]` you are actually assigning to `total_marks`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you very much I was able to fix my code now

Answer (score 0):

You are defining an array `marks[5]`, which only have elements from 0 to 4.
However, later on in a `for loop`, you try to access the 5th element of `marks` array, which is not-existant.
That leads to an error.

You for loop should be:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Comment: why was it giving the correct output when I wrote 'total_marks=marks[1]+marks[2]...+marks[5]" instead of the for loop then?

Comment: It could have got `marks[5]` as some next value in memory. However, when you're declaring an array with 5 elements in C++, then those elements have "addresses" -> 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: It worked by accident; undefined behavior is undefined. Consider again that, by coincidence, `marks[5]` and `total_marks` are one and the same, two names for the same value in memory. Then, in one case you have `total_marks = marks[0] + ... + marks[4] + total_marks`, and that happens to work because you assign to `total_marks` only once, after reading `marks[5]`. With the loop, you essentially do `marks[5] += marks[0]; marks[5] += marks[1]; ...; marks[5] += marks[5];` Written this way, it should be clear why every value ends up double-counted.